# PHP mysql not showing up admin panel feature

Tags: php, mysql, database, addition, edit

so i've been up for a long time working on this. So basically want I need to do is make an add, update, delete user table. Right now i'm currently just working on a table that shows what I have in my database and options to edite, delete, or add.

I have 2 tables in my database.

Links Table with the fields of : PID, LinkName, AnchorText, CategoryID, CategoryName
linkCategory table with the fields of : CategoryID, CategoryName

here's what I have so far.... and it's not showing up at all. No errors or anything.

```
<?php
// acquire shared info from other files
include("dbconn.inc.php"); // database connection 
include("shared.php"); // stored shared contents

// make database connection
$conn = dbConnect();

print $HTMLHeader; 
print $PageTitle;

?>
<script>
function confirmDel(title, pid) {
// javascript function to ask for deletion confirmation

    url = "admin_delete.php?pid="+pid;
    var agree = confirm("Delete this item: <" + title + "> ? ");
    if (agree) {
        // redirect to the deletion script
        location.href = url;
    }
    else {
        // do nothing
        return;
    }
}
</script>

<?php
// Retrieve the product & category info
$sql = "SELECT Links.PID, Links.AnchorText, linkCategory.CategoryName FROM Links, linkCategory where Links.CategoryID = linkCategory.CategoryID order by linkCategory.CategoryName";

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

if ($stmt->prepare($sql)){

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($PID, $Title, $CategoryName);

    $tblRows = "";
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $Title_js = htmlspecialchars($Title, ENT_QUOTES); // convert quotation marks in the product title to html entity code.  This way, the quotation marks won't cause trouble in the javascript function call ( href='javascript:confirmDel ...' ) below.  

        $tblRows = $tblRows."<tr><td>$Title</td>
                             <td>$CategoryName</td>
                             <td><a href='admin_form.php?pid=$PID'>Edit</a> | <a href='javascript:confirmDel(\"$Title_js\",$PID)'>Delete</a> </td></tr>";
    }

    $output = "<table border=1 cellpadding=4>\n
    <tr><th>Title</th><th>Category</th><th>Options</th></tr>\n".$tblRows.
    "</table>";

    $stmt->close();
} else {

    $output = "Query to retrieve product information failed.";

}

$conn->close();
?>


<?= $SubTitle_Admin ?>
<br>
| <a href="admin_form.php">Add a new item</a> |<br>

<?php echo $output ?>


<?php print $PageFooter; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my first page, I still have to put in the PHP for edit, update, and delete... but can't even get my main page to show up. A bit lengthy, but I need to get this done. If anyone could help me out, or point me the right direction... I would be grateful. Here is a link to what it should look like http://omega.uta.edu/~cyjang/ctec4321/lab/productList2/admin_productList.php. When I try to pull my own up it's a blank page... like this: http://omega.uta.edu/~dxh6110/4321/in%20class/linksadmin/admin_productList.php

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not showing up at all"? Do you get a blank  page? Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: I added a link to mine. It's just a blank page. The second one is mine.

Comment: ok at the top of the page just under the <?php tag, add: `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: welp that definitely helped, my DBconnect file were not in the same location. Thank you. It's showing the table now at least, lots of errors lol.

Comment: looks like you just need to just do the same for "shared.php" maybe

Comment: yes sir you are right. Thank you! That error things is very useful! i'll be using that more often. I should be able to do the rest now... but will post back if I run into anything. Thank you again sir!

Comment: cool. i'd recommend removing it once you're done. it's really only for development purposes.. you should never show errors this way on a site people use